# Save and Prompts users to Enter another value then Send to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to design a recruitment site in PHP/ Mysql.

When the user enters an educational Qualification, it saves and prompts the User to enter another one. I want to have it enter at least 3 educational Qualifications so that it can gather them and have them submitted to the MySQL database.

Comment: Did you have tried something? You already know which technology you need: PHP and MySQL. Please do some investigation in that technology and start write your code. This is a Q&A (= Question and Answer) site, not a "_code for me_" site. There are other sites for that.

Comment: @KarelG, yes i have tried something else i would not be asking. If i use $_POST it just gets the data and store in db, but i want it to get it at least 3 times then store in DB  for instance it gets inputs like this 

$institution_name = $_POST['institution_name'];
$gpa = $_POST['gpa'];
$degree_obtained = $_POST['degree_obtained'];


Now how does it get it and store, prompt to get another one store again at least for 3 times?